Installing GL driver killed my 24.04 machine
Someone at gitlab.freedesktop.org's forum adviced that I could get a minimal installation of GL drivers supporting AMD ROCm on 24.04 by use of the command,
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,dkms

After a minute of installation, a screen came up, looking like an old DOS screen, telling me that because I have secure boot enabled I was going to have to set a password, and enter it again upon reboot.  I entered a password, it gave me an error message I do not remember;  I hit PrintScreen to save it, but now I have no access to it.  Something about pkg returning error.  I entered reboot and it rebooted.
After the bios screen, another screen opened up asking me cryptic questions;  it had a main selection for boot, ubuntu and hash,  like, what could it possibly mean?  I selected ubuntu, and it presented me a number of arcane choices, incomprehensible;  I selected the first, then it asked for the password, I entered it, and nothing else I selected from those menus worked.  So I hit the reboot menu.
When it rebooted it showed me a white screen saying "Oh no! Something has gone wrong.  A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.  Please contact the administrator."  The bad news is I'm the administrator, and I have no idea what to do now.  I'm writing from my old laptop computer.  My new rig is dead.
So, it "was" 24.04 with MATE, the hardware being AM5 mobo, Ryzen 5, 32 gigs DDR5.
Anything I can do to revive it?
Would getting rid of secure boot help?

Aha! This is where I saw it. I could have sworn I saw the thing you wrote somewhere else. Yeah disable secure boot like I said. Another idea that could help people, help you, is record what’s happening with your phone. That way we can see these screens

That would have been a great idea, taking video of things.

But yeah it really doesn’t help if you install drivers on an unsupported OS. I’m sorry it killed your machine, but the drivers don’t support 24.04 for a reason. Having 22.04 isn’t a minimum requirement. If it supports the latest OS, it has to says it somewhere. Maybe you didn’t know that

Okay, I still don't understand.  I had, and still have no idea what the "sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,dkms" does.  You seemed to say it was going to fix my problem, and I just typed it in like an idiot.  But so, what part of it says that I'm installing 22.04 gl drivers, just so that next time I may know?

Sorry, I need to add on. This guy https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/nairboon from desktop said "You should be able to install the minimum drivers with just sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,dkms." But, I guess it isn't a guarantee that it works on 24.04, because it isn't supported. The place where you are supposed to download the drivers (which you mentioned at freedesktop) says what OSes are supported: https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers. I found some more documentation that might help: https://rocm.docs.amd.com/en/latest/.

Here is something that helps you with the installation commands

Nairboon also mentioned the command amdgpu-install --list-usecase which is how you could have found out what it was

Interesting read, but I still don't get where that statement forced an earlier version of the drivers.  No version was specified, anywhere I could see.  My feeling is that the problem was related to safe boot.  By the way, I'm basically done reinstalling.  I think I'm going to wait for the official release of AMD's drivers for 24.04, though.

i ran into the same issue today.
I got out of it by switching to a TTY Terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 or so.
Then i logged in and removed the amd driver with
sudo amdgpu-install --uninstall

Now i have a running and usable system, but without special drivers, so no gaming atm.
My research until now is that amdgpu really wants a kernel older than 6.4.
I will try to switch to an older kernel now.
Lets hope for updates.
Secureboot seems to be unimportant on this toppic.
Best regards
elektrohexer
[edit]
I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). After that the amdgpu-driver installed without bigger problems.

I spent a lot of time with the new 24.04.
I hope this helps because I'm not the most experienced Ubuntu user. Little remark.
Regarding the latest drivers, basic drivers will already be included out of the box. If things go really bad, it's better to roll back using Live USB or Grub. Yes, your can turn off Safe Boot.
They removed a bunch of x32 compatible libraries that were in the older driver versions. Therefore, you should probably wait before installing ROCm and other tools for working with PyTorch, etc.
You should roll back to the primary drivers and remove what you have already installed from tty (Ctrl+Alt+F3).
If you want to boot into the shell, you might need to update the configurations in Grub by specifying nomodset to boot with the basic graphics driver.
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodset"

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot

If you try to install everything according to these manuals, most likely nothing will work:
ROCm Installation Guide
Therefore, only the new driver update utility 6.2 amdgpu-install will work.
I was able to update only the graphics, everything else seems not fully supported. But with this, you can at least try to fix things back.
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics --no-32


Thanks for the help;  I'm the original question poster;  what I did was to reinstall Ubuntu, at the time.  As for getting ROCm drivers, they finally appeared for 24.04, but they only work with 7800 and 7900 cards;  the one I bought is a 7600 and I'm broke, so no ROCm for me any time soon.
